# Files.Count returning 0 in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, csom, vba

We are using the following code to attempt to retrieve a list of files in a SP 2013 library, but Files.Count is always returning 0. The same method works in a SP 2010 environment.

Are we missing anything or doing something wrong?

```
Dim folder As Folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl)
context.Load(folder)
context.ExecuteQuery()

'get the files
context.Load(folder.Files)
context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: this will give you the count of files from the folder at root url. are you sure your folder is at root url?

Answer (score 2):

See if the following code can help you.

```
ClientContext cxt = new ClientContext("http://YourSiteURL/");
        List list = cxt.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

        cxt.Load(list);
        cxt.Load(list.RootFolder);
        cxt.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
        cxt.Load(list.RootFolder.Files);
        cxt.ExecuteQuery();
        FolderCollection fcol = list.RootFolder.Folders;
        List<string> lstFile = new List<string>();
        foreach(Folder f in fcol)
        {
            if (f.Name == "filename")
            {
                cxt.Load(f.Files);
                cxt.ExecuteQuery();
                FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;
                foreach (File file in fileCol)
                {
                    lstFile.Add(file.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. We tried it and received a different error: 

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: List ''/sites/xxx/Shared Documents'' does not exist at site with URL ''http://servername''

The path is correct and was verified in the browser. I replaced the server name and site library when pasting.